# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/karzn/public_html/msg.php on line 56

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/karzn/public_html/msg.php on line 56

how to fixed this problem ?

```
enter code here
```

File Name : msg.php

---

php Code file download link : http://karzn.org/msg.php.zip

---

Please give me solution. please help me

Comment: Add the code as test. decide if mysql or SQL-Server. That are two very different thinks

Comment: Nobody is gonna download your zip file from a unknown source. - Either it's malicious or then there's most likely too much code.

Comment: You probably have not closed your PHP tag

Comment: how to solve this problem?

Comment: As a first step, please insert your code to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closed if condition in `if($opcode=="Banglalink" && $opcode=="GrameenPhone."){`. use like following

```
<?php

include("portal/open.php");
include("user_function.php");

$opcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['op']);
$sender = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['phone']);
$msg = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['msg']);
$simno = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['trid_prefix']);
$kode_inbox= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['st']);
$simno= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['sim']);


if($opcode=="Bkash"){
$sevid="4"; }else {$sevid="4";}

if($opcode=="Banglalink" && $opcode=="GrameenPhone.")
{
$simbal=substr($pt[19],0,-1);
$trxid="$pt[11]"; $gpphone=$pt[8]; 

$amount=number_format($pt[4]);
$gpno=substr($gpphone,0,10);
$phone="0".$gpno;
}
if($opcode=="robi" && $pt[3]!="transferred" )
{
$simbal="$pt[14]"; 
$trxid=substr($pt[10],0,-5);
$rbphone=$pt[4];
$amount=$pt[1];
$phone="0".$rbphone;
}

if($opcode=="Airtel" && $pt[0]!="8115:Transfer")
{
$simbal="$pt[15]"; $trxid="$pt[2]";
$phone=$pt[8]; $amount=$pt[5];
}


$sql="INSERT INTO `reportserver` (`id`, `servicid`, `msgbody`, `ucid`, `company`, `amt`, `transactionid`, `sender`, `number`, `f_id`, `datetime`, `idate`, `status`, `balance`, `is_sync`, `ownNumber`) VALUES (NULL, '$sevid', '$msg', '', '$opcode', '', '', '$phone', '', '', '', '', '', '$simbal', '0', NULL)";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die( 'Couldnot execute query'. mysql_error());



if($opcode=="GrameenPhone") { 
$opcode="gp";
}
if($opcode=="Banglalink") { 
$opcode="blink";
}

$sqladmin = mysql_query("UPDATE `sendflexi` SET `msg` = '$msg', status='1', trxid='$trxid', actual_send_time='$create_date', `simBalance` = '$simbal', `local` = '1' WHERE `sendflexi`.`phone` ='$phone' and balance='$amount' and `operator` LIKE '%$opcode%' and `status` ='4' order by id asc");

?>
```